# How To fix the "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" Error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'am trying to display a list based on a recyclerview seeing the amout of data i'll be dealing with it so huge, but whenever I try to excute the app, it is rendering but i got always this Error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout".

I've gone through the most of the solutions in the net but neither would work in my case.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        if (getArguments() != null) {
//            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
//            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
//        }
        Person person1 = new Person("xx", "xx", "xx");
        Person person2 = new Person("yy", "yy", "yy");
        Person person3 = new Person("zz", "zz", "zz");
        personList.add(person1);
        personList.add(person2);
        personList.add(person3);
        mContext= getContext();


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View personListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_person, container, false);
        personRecyclerView = personListView.findViewById(R.id.personRecyclerView);
        personRecyclerViewAdapter = new PersonListRecyclerAdapter(mContext, personList);
        personRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
//        recyclerViewLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        personRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        return personListView;
    }
```

I don't see what I am missing or what is wrong, any clue how to solve it?`enter code here`

Comment: You should see a lint error: personRecyclerViewAdapter is never used.

Answer (score 2):

It demands you to assign a `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
 personRecyclerView.setAdapter(personRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: When i cleanedThe code to post here i accidently deleted it, although i added it it still not working.

Comment: @Bayram the code you've posted only permits to assume what `personRecyclerView` & `PersonListRecyclerAdapter` are; that's not really a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). one can also attach the adapter in the `RecyclerView` constructor (which is how I usually organize that). even attaching an empty adapter suppresses this warning message (the timing might play a role).

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your `RecyclerView` which adapter you want it to use to get the data. This is done with `setAdapter()` method ([see docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter))):

```
personRecyclerView.setAdapter(personRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: When i cleanedThe code to post here i accidently deleted it, although i added it it still not working.